# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Trying to initialize passport and getting this error.

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/seanburnett/Desktop/Zero to Blockchain/Module 6/Homework/final-project/server/config/passport.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);


import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js'
import userRoutes from './routes/user.js'
import loginRoutes from './routes/login.js'

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
app.use('/auth', userRoutes);
app.use('/login', loginRoutes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change it to this

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const URL = createRequire(import.meta.url); // <-- You had reset the require here.


import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js'
import userRoutes from './routes/user.js'
import loginRoutes from './routes/login.js'

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
app.use('/auth', userRoutes);
app.use('/login', loginRoutes);
```

Comment: I get ReferenceError: require is not defined. When I do that

Comment: @SeanBurnett did you find any solution for this error?